# Trying to cover 100% of parent div width (excluding padding) between 2 child divs.

Tags: html, css

Here is my CSS so far. It seems like the parent div's left-padding is fine (i.e. not covered by a child div), but its right padding is covered by a child div. Any thoughts?

```
.div_parent {
    position: absolute;
    height: 720px;
    width: 600px;
    top: 30px;
    background-color: blue;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.div_child1 {
    position: absolute;
    height: inherit;
    width: 15%;
    background-color: tan;
}

.div_child2 {
    position: absolute;
    height: inherit;
    width: 85%;
    left: 15%;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Here is my html too:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='calendar.css' >
        <script src='calendar.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class = 'div_parent'>
            <div class = 'div_child1'>
                <h1>test</h1>
                <p>test2</p>
                <p>test3</p>
            </div>
            <div class = 'div_child2'>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the problem is that you haven't given the 'left' of first child and is auto by default and for second child you have given 15%. Also when calculating width of children you have to account for the parent's padding which you haven't. If you add up the total width of children, it is equal to the width of parent i.e. 620 so by calculation, there isn't enough space in parent div for both of them to stack side by side. One better solution to the problem is to use left floating block divs or better use calc() to account for the padding.

```
.child-1{
width:calc(15% - 10px);
}

.child-2{
width:calc(85% - 10px);
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zNzfL/)

Comment: Use calc() with floating divs, remove parent's absolute position if you don't need it and you will be good to go even when the resolution changes.

Comment: gsheld I am glad to be of help. Can you choose the best answer if you don't mind? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use float: left; on both divs and take away the left: 15%; and the position: absolute;